# How to efficiently include external JS dependencies in a Blogger-hosted blog

Tags: hosting, colorbox, blogger

My scenario:

1. There's a blog that runs on **Blogger**, and that's also where it's hosted. Afaik, "external" (js) files cannot be hosted on Google's servers.
2. When it comes to including popular JS frameworks (*e.g.,* **jQuery**), there are several **[CDN](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#CDN_Hosted_jQuery)** options at our disposal.
3. Looking for a jQuery-based Lightbox replacement for a blog, I've stumbled upon **[ColorBox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/)**; no plans to have a CDN for it though.

So far, when it comes to including/hosting the files under the given constraints, I've noticed the following suggestions/solutions:

1. Including the minified version of the code *inline* in the Blogger template -- 9KB worth of JS code in a `<script>` element.
2. Linking directly to the **github** raw version -- *e.g.,* [v1.3.16](https://github.com/jackmoore/colorbox/raw/v1.3.16/colorbox/jquery.colorbox-min.js). (*unreliable availability?*)

Considering **load speeds** and **availability** what is the **best practice** for this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you describe, I don't see much benefit to not including the code in the Blogger template.  It's arguably small enough that anyone not sucking their internet through a straw will not notice the increased time to download the page source, and it will certainly be faster overall than loading from a remote server, so it looks like the only likely performance hit is that you might have decreased responsiveness (time until the user can interact with the page), but it should only be noticeable if the user happens to have an especially narrow connection.

So, you'll have to consider your users, but unless an extraordinary number of them have narrow connections, just include the code inline.